# PreValidation in Symfony 1.4 for embedForm with sfValidatorCallback

Tags: validation, symfony1, symfony-forms

I have a SymfonyForm which has 1:n embedForm(s). The main form and the embedForm class got their own PreValidation, which implements a conditional validation.
A part of the EmbedForm class looks like this:

```
private function configurePreValidators() {
    $validator = new sfValidatorCallback( array('callback'=> array($this, 'preValidation')) );
    $this->getValidatorSchema()->setPreValidator(new sfValidatorOr( array( $validator ) ));
}

public function preValidation(sfValidatorCallback $validator, array $values){
...
    $this->getValidator(self::SOME_FIELD)->setOption('required', false);
...
}
public function configure() {
    ...
    $this->configurePreValidators();
    parent::configure();
}
```

The prevalidation of the main form is similar.

When I submit the form, the main form prevalidation works fine.

In the embed-Form the "SOME_FIELD" gets a required-validation-error although I set it explicit to *setOption('required', false)* in the preValidation of the embedForm.

Is there something what I have to consider when I use pre-validation in an embedForm? What about [mergePreValidator](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfForm#method_mergeprevalidator)? Any hints about that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is not that your pre and post validators aren't firing -- they are (or at least, they should be). The issue is that the validator you are modifying is preValidate is not the one referenced in the top-level validator schema, i.e. the validator schema for the top-level form.

One solution: rather than modify the validator in preValidate, simply perform the validation:

```
public function preValidation(sfValidatorCallback $validator, array $values)
{
  if (!$this->getValidator(self::SOME_FIELD)->isEmpty($values[self::SOME_FIELD])
  {
    throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema(self::SOME_FIELD => new sfValdiatorError($validator, 'msg'));
  }
}
```

Note, this solution has some danger: **if you modify the validator for SOME_FIELD inside of the top-level form, it will not be modified in this pre validator and vice-versa**.

Let's look at why. In sfForm::embedForm:

```
public function embedForm($name, sfForm $form, $decorator = null)
{
  ...
  $this->validatorSchema[$name] = $form->getValidatorSchema();
  ...
}
```

Symfony simply nests the validators. This is why pre and post still get called. Why does the reference change? sfValidatorSchema::offsetSet:

```
public function offsetSet($name, $validator)
{
  ...    
  $this->fields[$name] = clone $validator;
}
```

So when a form is embedded, the validator schema is cloned. Thus, any modifications to the validators inside of an embedded form do not affect the top-level validator schema.

Comment: This won't help in my top-level form class?

foreach ($this->getEmbeddedForm('my_embeded_forms')->getEmbeddedForms() as $form_id=>$form) {
    $this->mergePreValidator($form->getValidatorSchema());
}

???

Comment: No, sfForm::embedForm is already merging the schemas in the code I pasted above. The preValidators ARE FIRING they're simply modifying the wrong validator instance.

Comment: It would be interresting to know, on which version of symfony does this work, if you remember ? the isEmtpy method is protected in sf 1.4 and 1.2, thus it is not possible to call it from the form class

Comment: So it is! My guess is that this specific example never actually worked. Still, the general explanation is correct.